# extjs - How to disable pagination on a store

Tags: extjs, pagination, extjs4.2

Whenever a store (`Ext.data.Store`) reads data from the server, it sends paging parameters like `&page=1&start=0&limit=25` in a `json` proxy or `[page:1, start:0, limit:25]` using a `direct` proxy.

I'd like to disable paging in the store or proxy configuration.

I found this workaround, but I'm sure there must be a better method.

```
proxy: {
    pageParam: undefined,
    startParam: undefined,
    limitParam: undefined,
    ...
}
```

Does anyone know how to disable paging properly ?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to apply this workaround when creating stores in Sencha Architect v2.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
store: {
    pageSize: 0,
    limit:0,
....
}
```

excluding from the request

page: __

start: __

limit: ___

Comment: For my stores with localstorage proxy, I used `store.load({limit: 1})` successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to override the proxy's `getParams` method. This handles the groupers, sorters, filters, page, start and limit parameters.
It's defined in `Ext.data.proxy.Server`

If you want to disable all Extjs used parameters, then you can simple replace it with an empty method:

```
proxy: {
    getParams: Ext.emptyFn,
    ...
}
```

You can also extend the proxy class and override this method.

Comment: This would disable all the parameter functionality. This is not intended.

Comment: You can also extend the proxy class and override this method and not only with `Ext.emptyFn`, but with a customized `getParams` method

Answer (score 2):

I set:

```
pageSize: 0,
```

in the model config.

Answer (score 0):

To disable pagination, you have to set the values to empty string, not undefined. Like so:

```
pageParam: '',
startParam: '',
limitParam: '',
```

This works for me in Ext JS 6.2

Comment: `undefined` also works. This is not an improvement for me.

Answer (score -2):

set the following on the store:

```
{
    defaultPageSize: null
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It has no effect on pagination.