# Extjs 4.2 Grid is not displaying all the records

Tags: extjs4.2

I have grid with around 1500 records and also have the pagination with 50 records per page.But whenever I increase the page size to 1000,it is not showing up all the records.However my json call return all the 1000 records
Why the grid is not showing all the records.
Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks,

Comment: Why would you paginate at all, 1000 lines never can hold on a screen ?

Comment: I have implementation in such a way that I could import the data what was there in current page.So I was trying to increase page size to import all the records in the grid.

Comment: Why not just deactivate pagination ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397359/extjs-how-to-disable-pagination-on-a-store

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I set the ajax time out to 2 minutes. However it was taking more than two minutes .Seems there exist performance issue. I need to correct the logic in such a way that it should pull all the records in minimum time.